# Click Long On Image using Robotium

Tags: robotium

I want my test to click on an image for about 20-30 seconds, How can I achieve this with current robotium version.

Answer (score 2):

solo.clickLongOnView(view, time); if image is a view or solo.clickLongOnScreen(x, y, time);